# Возникает ошибка компиляции CS0120 при обращении к кнопке на другой форме

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть три формы — главное меню, `Param` и `LectureForm`. Главное меню вызывает обе другие формы.

`LectureForm` - вызывается через кнопку главного меню. `Param` вызывается через менюстрип главного меню, она является чем-то вроде настроек.

`Param` настраивает `LectureForm`. То есть формы открываются по очереди. Сначала я выбираю файл и т.д. А потом захожу в `LectureForm`

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на CheckBox в `Param` кнопка в `LectureForm` исчезала и появлялась.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Victorina
{
    public partial class Param : Form
    {
        public Param()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Param_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(Victorina.list.ToArray());
            checkBox1.Checked = true;

        }

        private void btnSelectFolder_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {
                string[] video_list = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.mp4", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                Victorina.lastFolder = fbd.SelectedPath;
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(video_list);
                Victorina.list.Clear();
                Victorina.list.AddRange(video_list);
            }
        }

        private void btnClearList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void btnOK_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Victorina.WriteParam();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            listBox1.Visible = true;
            checkBox2.Checked = false;
            listBox2.Visible = false;

            LectureForm.btnNext.Visible = true;
            LectureForm.WMP.Visible = true;

        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка компиляции:

> Ошибка CS0120 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "LectureForm.btnNext" требуется ссылка на объект

на строке `LectureForm.btnNext.Visible = true;`

Comment: А расскажите как между собой связаны формы `LectureForm` и `Param`. Которая из них вызывает другую например?

Comment: Вообще у меня больше, форм. У меня есть 3 форма - главное меню, которое вызывает и ту и другую. Но Param настраивает LectureForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Почему возникает ошибка

`LectureForm` — это класс формы, таких форм можно создать сколько угодно.

`btnNext` — это свойство экземпляра класса формы. Это кнопка, которая лежит на конкретном экземпляре формы.

Ошибка говорит о том, что Вы пытаетесь через класс обратиться к свойству объекта этого класса, так делать нельзя.

### Общие данные

Т.к. `LectureForm` показывается отдельно от `Param`, то обратиться к объекту `LectureForm` нельзя т.к. форма еще не создана.

В этом случае нужно чтобы `Param` записала данные куда-нибудь откуда `lectureForm` может их считать.

Можно например объявить глобальное статическое поле в каком-нибудь классе. Например, в том же `Param` сделать ему значение по-умолчанию false и изменять его при нажатии на checkbox:

```
//поле внутри класса `Param`
public static bool LectureFormButtonsVisible = true;

...
//установка в обработчике checkBox
listBox2.Visible = false;

LectureFormButtonsVisible = checkBox1.Checked;
```

Потом при отображении `LectureForm` это поле можно будет считать:

```
private void LectureForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnNext.Visible = Param.LectureFormButtonsVisible;
    WMP.Visible = Param.LectureFormButtonsVisible;
}
```

Как будет время почитайте про проекты проектирования, про то как можно отделить интерфейс от логики. При правильной архитектуре приложения у форм будет доступ к общей модели и они сами будут реагировать на изменение. Построение такой архитектуры сильно зависит от Вашего приложения и, пожалуй, сильно выходит за рамки этого вопроса.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94092/discussion-on-answer-by-default-locale----cs0120--).